# Robot Framework - Unsupported Media Type error

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I have the following json file:

```
{
   "company":[
      {
         "name":"My company",
         "security":"WPA2-PSK"
      }
   ],
   "name":"one name"
}
```

I'm trying to send a POST based on this json file but it's getting an error.

My code looks like this:

```
Create new company
${headers} =  Create Dictionary   Accept=application/json    Content-Type=application/json
${body} =    Get file  create.json
Create Session    http_session   ${url}   disable_warnings=${True}
${response} = POST On Session   http_session  ${company}  data=${body} headers=${headers}
```

But I get the following error:

```
POST Response:
headers={'content-type': 'application/json', 'vary': 'Accept, Origin, Cookie', 'allow': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS', 'x-frame-options': 'DENY', 'content-length': '52', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'referrer-policy': 'same-origin', 'set-cookie': '64bc588b56c7114f53411b945693e29ba=55323dcbd60f99b6aa8cfcb0f44f578e; path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None'} 
 body={"detail":"Unsupported media type \"\" in request."} 

HTTPError: 415 Client Error: Unsupported Media Type for url: myUrl
```

So I did:

```
Create new company
${headers} =  Create Dictionary   Accept=application/json    Content-Type=application/json

${json1} =  Get file  create.json
${json} =   Evaluate  json.dumps(${json1})
${body} =  Evaluate  json.loads('''${json}''')  json
Create Session    http_session   ${url}   disable_warnings=${True}
${response} = POST On Session   http_session  ${company}  data=${body} headers=${headers}
```

so i got the same error.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What does the documentation for the API call say? Does it return data in json format?

Comment: yes, return data in json format.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem in converting json. I did it like this:

`${body} =  Evaluate  json.loads("""${json}""")`

Now it worked.